# Sending an email with Amazon SES - Using User Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-ses

I am using .NET Core and C#. This code is in an action method here to send an email with Amazon SES. I have replaced the email, username, and password with my own credentials, and I am only able to send messages to the email I have specified here, 
but I would like to configure this so that I am able to send messages to a specified email in a form. How am I able to do this?

```
 String FROM = "sender@example.com";
 String FROMNAME = "Sender Name";
 String TO = "recipient@amazon.com";
 String SMTP_USERNAME = "smtp_username";
 String SMTP_PASSWORD = "smtp_password";
 String CONFIGSET = "ConfigSet";
 String HOST = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";

 int PORT = 587;

 String SUBJECT =
 "Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using C#)";
 String BODY =
 "<h1>Amazon SES Test</h1>" +
 "<p>This email was sent through the " +
 "<a href='https://aws.amazon.com/ses'>Amazon SES</a> SMTP interface " +
 "using the .NET System.Net.Mail library.</p>";
 MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
 message.IsBodyHtml = true;
 message.From = new MailAddress(FROM, FROMNAME);
 message.To.Add(new MailAddress(TO));
 message.Subject = SUBJECT;
 message.Body = BODY;
 message.Headers.Add("X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET", CONFIGSET);
 using (var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(HOST, PORT))
 {
 client.Credentials =
 new NetworkCredential(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
 client.EnableSsl = true;
 try
 {
 Console.WriteLine("Attempting to send email...");
 client.Send(message);
 Console.WriteLine("Email sent!");
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent.");
 Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + ex.Message);
 }
 }
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: Well you hardcoded the `TO` value. Did you think about maybe allowing the value to be set to some other value from some other location?

Comment: consider using the AWS SDK

Comment: @nate This code is presumably in a method, right? And you know how to add parameters to methods? And how to pass a method to a parameter when calling it?

Answer (score 0):

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;


// Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
// This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
String FROM = "yoursender@mail.com";
String FROMNAME = "Name";

// Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account
// is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
String TO = "receiver@mail.com";

// Replace smtp_username with your Amazon SES SMTP user name.
String SMTP_USERNAME = "username_from_aws_ses";

// Replace smtp_password with your Amazon SES SMTP password.
String SMTP_PASSWORD = "password
_from_aws_ses";

// (Optional) the name of a configuration set to use for this message.
// If you comment out this line, you also need to remove or comment out
// the "X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET" header below.
String CONFIGSET = "ConfigSet";

// If you're using Amazon SES in a region other than US West (Oregon),
// replace email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com with the Amazon SES SMTP  
// endpoint in the appropriate AWS Region.
String HOST = "email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com";

// The port you will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint. We
// are choosing port 587 because we will use STARTTLS to encrypt
// the connection.
int PORT = 587;

// The subject line of the email
String SUBJECT =
    "Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using C#)";

// The body of the email
String BODY =
    "<h1>Amazon SES Test</h1>" +
    "<p>This email was sent through the " +
    "<a href='https://aws.amazon.com/ses'>Amazon SES</a> SMTP interface " +
    "using the .NET System.Net.Mail library.</p>";

// Create and build a new MailMessage object
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.From = new MailAddress(FROM, FROMNAME);
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(TO));
message.Subject = SUBJECT;
message.Body = BODY;
// Comment or delete the next line if you are not using a configuration set
//message.Headers.Add("X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET", CONFIGSET);

using (var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(HOST, PORT))
{
    // Pass SMTP credentials
    client.Credentials =
        new NetworkCredential(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

    // Enable SSL encryption
    client.EnableSsl = true;

    // Try to send the message. Show status in console.
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Attempting to send email...");
        client.Send(message);
        Console.WriteLine("Email sent!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent.");
        Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```